# python ontimer vs thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading, turtle-graphics

This is an extension of my recent post. Now that I know about onTimer and Thread, starting a new post.

I did away w/ the while loop in the main. Replaced with onTimer() and Thread. But same results, cant move both objects simultaneously. Code for both listed below: Any advice is appreciated...this is my first go at graphics w/ Python.

## code using onTimer

```
import turtle
import math

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.screensize(1000, 1000)
screen.bgcolor("light green")

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.hideturtle()
player.penup()
player.shape("circle")
player.color("red")
player.fillcolor("yellow")
player.setposition(-50, -40)
player.showturtle()
player.speed(0)

s = turtle.Turtle()
s.hideturtle()
s.penup()
s.shape("square")
s.color("black")
s.fillcolor("white")
s.setposition(-50, -60)
s.showturtle()

# first tier
s1 = turtle.Turtle()
s1.hideturtle()
s1.penup()
s1.shape("square")
s1.color("black")
s1.fillcolor("white")
s1.showturtle()

s2 = turtle.Turtle()
s2.hideturtle()
s2.penup()
s2.shape("square")
s2.color("black")
s2.fillcolor("white")
s2.setposition(s1.xcor() + 20, 0)
s2.showturtle()

s3 = turtle.Turtle()
s3.hideturtle()
s3.penup()
s3.shape("square")
s3.color("black")
s3.fillcolor("white")
s3.setposition(s2.xcor() + 20, 0)
s3.showturtle()

s4 = turtle.Turtle()
s4.hideturtle()
s4.penup()
s4.shape("square")
s4.color("black")
s4.fillcolor("white")
s4.setposition(s3.xcor() + 20, 0)
s4.showturtle()

# second tier
s5 = turtle.Turtle()
s5.hideturtle()
s5.penup()
s5.shape("square")
s5.color("black")
s5.fillcolor("white")
s5.setposition(s4.xcor() + 30, 60)
s5.showturtle()

s6 = turtle.Turtle()
s6.hideturtle()
s6.penup()
s6.shape("square")
s6.color("black")
s6.fillcolor("white")
s6.setposition(s5.xcor() + 20, 60)
s6.showturtle()

s7 = turtle.Turtle()
s7.hideturtle()
s7.penup()
s7.shape("square")
s7.color("black")
s7.fillcolor("white")
s7.setposition(s6.xcor() + 20, 60)
s7.showturtle()

s8 = turtle.Turtle()
s8.hideturtle()
s8.penup()
s8.shape("square")
s8.color("black")
s8.fillcolor("white")
s8.setposition(s7.xcor() + 20, 60)
s8.showturtle()

# third tier
s9 = turtle.Turtle()
s9.hideturtle()
s9.penup()
s9.shape("square")
s9.color("black")
s9.fillcolor("white")
s9.setposition(s8.xcor() + 30, 120)
s9.showturtle()

s10 = turtle.Turtle()
s10.hideturtle()
s10.penup()
s10.shape("square")
s10.color("black")
s10.fillcolor("white")
s10.setposition(s9.xcor() + 20, 120)
s10.showturtle()

s11 = turtle.Turtle()
s11.hideturtle()
s11.penup()
s11.shape("square")
s11.color("black")
s11.fillcolor("white")
s11.setposition(s10.xcor() + 20, 120)
s11.showturtle()

s12 = turtle.Turtle()
s12.hideturtle()
s12.penup()
s12.shape("square")
s12.color("black")
s12.fillcolor("white")
s12.setposition(s11.xcor() + 20, 120)
s12.showturtle()

#moving enemy
s13 = turtle.Turtle()
s13.hideturtle()
s13.penup()
s13.shape("square")
s13.color("black")
s13.fillcolor("red")
s13.setposition(s11.xcor() + 5, 140)
s13.showturtle()

#static turtle
s14 = turtle.Turtle()
s14.hideturtle()
s14.penup()
s14.shape("turtle")
s14.color("black")
s14.fillcolor("red")
s14.setposition(s6.xcor() + 20, 80)
s14.showturtle()

squareList = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12]

falling = False

def jump():
    speed = 2

    while speed > 0:
        y = player.ycor()
        x = player.xcor()
        y += 6
        x += 1.3
        speed -= 0.09
        player.setposition(x, y)
        collision()
    if speed < 0:
        falling = True
        while falling:
            y = player.ycor()
            x = player.xcor()
            y -= 2
            x += 1
            speed += .10
            player.setposition(x, y)
            collision()
            for squares in squareList:
                if (player.xcor() >= 0 and player.xcor() <= 80) and player.ycor() == 20:
                    falling = False
                if (player.xcor() >= 80 and player.xcor() <= 160) and player.ycor() == 80:
                    falling = False
                if (player.xcor() >= 160 and player.xcor() <= 240) and player.ycor() == 140:
                    falling = False


def right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += 2
    player.setx(x)
    collision()

def moveEnemy():
    s13.backward(3)
    if s13.xcor() > 250:
        s13.setheading(0)
    if s13.xcor() < 180:
        s13.setheading(180)
    screen.ontimer(moveEnemy(), 5)
    collision()

def collision():
    distance1 = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor()-s13.xcor(),2) + math.pow(player.ycor()-s13.ycor(), 2))
    if distance1 < 20:
        player.hideturtle()

    distance2 = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor() - s14.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player.ycor() - s14.ycor(), 2))
    if distance2 < 20:
        s14.hideturtle()

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(jump, "Up")
turtle.onkey(right, "Right")

screen.ontimer(moveEnemy(), 5)

turtle.mainloop()
```

## code using Thread

```
import turtle
import math
import threading
from threading import Thread

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.screensize(1000, 1000)
screen.bgcolor("light green")

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.hideturtle()
player.penup()
player.shape("circle")
player.color("red")
player.fillcolor("yellow")
player.setposition(-50, -40)
player.showturtle()
player.speed(0)

s = turtle.Turtle()
s.hideturtle()
s.penup()
s.shape("square")
s.color("black")
s.fillcolor("white")
s.setposition(-50, -60)
s.showturtle()

# first tier
s1 = turtle.Turtle()
s1.hideturtle()
s1.penup()
s1.shape("square")
s1.color("black")
s1.fillcolor("white")
s1.showturtle()

s2 = turtle.Turtle()
s2.hideturtle()
s2.penup()
s2.shape("square")
s2.color("black")
s2.fillcolor("white")
s2.setposition(s1.xcor() + 20, 0)
s2.showturtle()

s3 = turtle.Turtle()
s3.hideturtle()
s3.penup()
s3.shape("square")
s3.color("black")
s3.fillcolor("white")
s3.setposition(s2.xcor() + 20, 0)
s3.showturtle()

s4 = turtle.Turtle()
s4.hideturtle()
s4.penup()
s4.shape("square")
s4.color("black")
s4.fillcolor("white")
s4.setposition(s3.xcor() + 20, 0)
s4.showturtle()

# second tier
s5 = turtle.Turtle()
s5.hideturtle()
s5.penup()
s5.shape("square")
s5.color("black")
s5.fillcolor("white")
s5.setposition(s4.xcor() + 30, 60)
s5.showturtle()

s6 = turtle.Turtle()
s6.hideturtle()
s6.penup()
s6.shape("square")
s6.color("black")
s6.fillcolor("white")
s6.setposition(s5.xcor() + 20, 60)
s6.showturtle()

s7 = turtle.Turtle()
s7.hideturtle()
s7.penup()
s7.shape("square")
s7.color("black")
s7.fillcolor("white")
s7.setposition(s6.xcor() + 20, 60)
s7.showturtle()

s8 = turtle.Turtle()
s8.hideturtle()
s8.penup()
s8.shape("square")
s8.color("black")
s8.fillcolor("white")
s8.setposition(s7.xcor() + 20, 60)
s8.showturtle()

# third tier
s9 = turtle.Turtle()
s9.hideturtle()
s9.penup()
s9.shape("square")
s9.color("black")
s9.fillcolor("white")
s9.setposition(s8.xcor() + 30, 120)
s9.showturtle()

s10 = turtle.Turtle()
s10.hideturtle()
s10.penup()
s10.shape("square")
s10.color("black")
s10.fillcolor("white")
s10.setposition(s9.xcor() + 20, 120)
s10.showturtle()

s11 = turtle.Turtle()
s11.hideturtle()
s11.penup()
s11.shape("square")
s11.color("black")
s11.fillcolor("white")
s11.setposition(s10.xcor() + 20, 120)
s11.showturtle()

s12 = turtle.Turtle()
s12.hideturtle()
s12.penup()
s12.shape("square")
s12.color("black")
s12.fillcolor("white")
s12.setposition(s11.xcor() + 20, 120)
s12.showturtle()

#moving enemy
s13 = turtle.Turtle()
s13.hideturtle()
s13.penup()
s13.shape("square")
s13.color("black")
s13.fillcolor("red")
s13.setposition(s11.xcor() + 5, 140)
s13.showturtle()

#static turtle
s14 = turtle.Turtle()
s14.hideturtle()
s14.penup()
s14.shape("turtle")
s14.color("black")
s14.fillcolor("red")
s14.setposition(s6.xcor() + 20, 80)
s14.showturtle()

squareList = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12]

falling = False

def jump():
    speed = 2

    while speed > 0:
        y = player.ycor()
        x = player.xcor()
        y += 6
        x += 1.3
        speed -= 0.09
        player.setposition(x, y)
        collision()
    if speed < 0:
        falling = True
        while falling:
            y = player.ycor()
            x = player.xcor()
            y -= 2
            x += 1
            speed += .10
            player.setposition(x, y)
            collision()
            for squares in squareList:
                if (player.xcor() >= 0 and player.xcor() <= 80) and player.ycor() == 20:
                    falling = False
                if (player.xcor() >= 80 and player.xcor() <= 160) and player.ycor() == 80:
                    falling = False
                if (player.xcor() >= 160 and player.xcor() <= 240) and player.ycor() == 140:
                    falling = False


def right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += 2
    player.setx(x)
    collision()

def moveEnemy():
    s13.backward(3)
    if s13.xcor() > 250:
        s13.setheading(0)
    if s13.xcor() < 180:
        s13.setheading(180)
    screen.ontimer(moveEnemy(), 5)
    collision()

def collision():
    distance1 = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor()-s13.xcor(),2) + math.pow(player.ycor()-s13.ycor(), 2))
    if distance1 < 20:
        player.hideturtle()

    distance2 = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor() - s14.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player.ycor() - s14.ycor(), 2))
    if distance2 < 20:
        s14.hideturtle()

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(jump, "Up")
turtle.onkey(right, "Right")

Thread(target = moveEnemy).start()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: fyi: the threaded version seems to be working reasonably well now. when i tested it home last night, the s13 would pause when the player was in jump mode. today at work (i'm a teacher), there's only a slight pause when both objects are moving. my first time using threading, interesting...

Comment: ...the threaded version is using both ontimer( ) and a thread. replaced while loop w/ ontimer() in the moveEnemy( ). Used a thread to invoke the moveEnemy( ) so the two combined seem to produce the results I was after...

Comment: There's no clear question here, especially as assuming we know what your previous post was.

Answer (score 0):

You made the same error as in your original code, where you made the motion atomic -- you can't stop everything `while` you implement the jump.  You need to break the jump into discrete steps.  Here's my `ontimer()` based solution:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(1000, 1000)
screen.bgcolor('light green')

player = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
player.penup()
player.color('red', 'yellow')
player.setposition(-50, -40)
player.showturtle()
player.speed('fastest')

s = Turtle('square', visible=False)
s.penup()
s.color('black', 'white')
s.setposition(-50, -60)
s.showturtle()

# first tier
s1 = Turtle('square', visible=False)
s1.penup()
s1.color('black', 'white')

s2 = s1.clone()
s2.setx(s1.xcor() + 20)
s2.showturtle()

s3 = s1.clone()
s3.setx(s2.xcor() + 20)
s3.showturtle()

s4 = s1.clone()
s4.setx(s3.xcor() + 20)
s4.showturtle()

s1.showturtle()

# second tier
s5 = Turtle('square', visible=False)
s5.penup()
s5.color('black', 'white')
s5.setposition(s4.xcor() + 30, 60)

s6 = s5.clone()
s6.setx(s5.xcor() + 20)
s6.showturtle()

s7 = s5.clone()
s7.setx(s6.xcor() + 20)
s7.showturtle()

s8 = s5.clone()
s8.setx(s7.xcor() + 20)
s8.showturtle()

s5.showturtle()

# third tier
s9 = Turtle('square', visible=False)
s9.penup()
s9.color('black', 'white')
s9.setposition(s8.xcor() + 30, 120)

s10 = s9.clone()
s10.setx(s9.xcor() + 20)
s10.showturtle()

s11 = s9.clone()
s11.setx(s10.xcor() + 20)
s11.showturtle()

s12 = s9.clone()
s12.setx(s11.xcor() + 20)
s12.showturtle()

s9.showturtle()

# moving enemy
s13 = Turtle('square', visible=False)
s13.penup()
s13.color('black', 'red')
s13.setposition(s11.xcor() + 5, 140)
s13.showturtle()

# static turtle
s14 = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
s14.penup()
s14.color('black', 'red')
s14.setposition(s6.xcor() + 20, 80)
s14.showturtle()

squareList = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12]

RISING, FALLING = 0, 1
state = None
speed = -1

def jump():
    global speed, state
    speed = 2
    state = RISING
    screen.ontimer(jumping, 7)

def jumping():
    global speed, state

    if state == RISING:
        x, y = player.position()
        y += 6
        x += 1.3
        speed -= 0.09
        player.setposition(x, y)
        collision()

    if speed < 0:
        state = FALLING

    if state == FALLING:
        x, y = player.position()
        y -= 2
        x += 1
        speed += 0.10
        player.setposition(x, y)
        collision()

        for _ in squareList:
            if (0 <= player.xcor() <= 80) and player.ycor() == 20:
                state = None
            if (80 <= player.xcor() <= 160) and player.ycor() == 80:
                state = None
            if (160 <= player.xcor() <= 240) and player.ycor() == 140:
                state = None

    if state in [RISING, FALLING]:
        screen.ontimer(jumping, 7)

def right():
    player.setx(player.xcor() + 2)
    collision()

def moveEnemy():
    s13.backward(3)
    if s13.xcor() > 250:
        s13.setheading(0)
    elif s13.xcor() < 180:
        s13.setheading(180)
    screen.ontimer(moveEnemy(), 5)
    collision()

def collision():
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor() - s13.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player.ycor() - s13.ycor(), 2))
    if distance < 20:
        player.hideturtle()

    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor() - s14.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player.ycor() - s14.ycor(), 2))
    if distance < 20:
        s14.hideturtle()

screen.onkey(jump, 'Up')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

screen.ontimer(moveEnemy(), 5)

screen.mainloop()
```

I also reworked other stuff while I was at it, tossing 30% of your code.  There's still stuff you need to add about stopping the jumping timer when the player collides or falls off the bottom of the window.

Comment: I understand what you mean about breaking into discrete steps. Actually I was thinking the same thing but didnt know how to implement it...Not sure how the ontimer keeps the s13 object moving constantly. Does it call function repeatedly after a set time?

Comment: @chappie, no, the `ontimer()` is a one-shot.  For continuous movement, the function that gets called by the timer sets up a new timer just before it returns.  That way, when conditions are right, it can also end the cycle.

Comment: i see. is the ontimer( ) 2nd parameter, the time between calls to the func? that's the discrete part, there's gaps between each call. seems to me there would be a pause in motion in the gaps.

Comment: when timers are created do they run in separate threads by nature or are they part of the main thread?

Comment: @chappie, my unverified belief is that the ontimer events are part of the main (sole) thread.  While it's in the process of checking if there are any mouse, keyboard, etc. events, it also checks for timer events.  As far as the gaps between events, there is computer time and there is human time.  Motion pictures run at 24 frames a second but they look continuous.  If the event loop is executing our timer even close to our requested rate, that's an equivalent of a rate in excess of 100 frames per second.

Comment: i know we are not supposed to use comments to say thanks but "thanks!".
this discussion has been very beneficial...i appreciate it.

Comment: Now I see how the program can be discrete with a frame rate that speed. You explain it well...question about the event loop. is the event loop invoked/created by the turtle.listen( )?
Makes sense now. Event listeners waiting for events: mouse click, timers, etc and executes the code associated w/ the event. The event listener is the atomic loop, no? The events themselves are discrete w/in the event loop. I see now why my orig approach w/ an atomic loop in the main was no good.

Comment: @chappie, no `turtle.listen()` just allows the turtle window to receive keyboard events.  I.e. it changes an event mask and/or makes the window the current listener.  The last line of the program, `screen.mainloop()` (aka `done()` aka `exitonclick()`) turns control over to Tkinter's main event loop (which turns control over to Tk's main event loop...)